# Is there a practical way to manage a physical task board if one or more scrum team members works remotely?

Tags: scrum, task-organization

I've convinced a few colleagues to try scrum with me, but one of them works remotely. We'd like to try using a physical task board.

I think we might be able to pull it off by snapping a photo and sending it to him every time the board is updated, and when he wants to update any of his tasks at the end of the day, he can just ask me to do it for him. It seems simple enough, but I'm not sure if we would be better off just using an online task board like Trello.

We're also considering managing a physical board and a Trello board but would like to avoid dual maintenance.

Has anyone implemented scrum with a physical task board shared with remote team members? If so, what worked and what didn't work?

Comment: This is 2015, and we still don't have a way to do this with a computer?

Comment: Can you explain why a physical task board would be necessary and the virtual task board supported by the many Agile development life cycle tools out there, would not be sufficient?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree. I use Trello to organize my different projects and I find it effective. However, I also bought myself a $300 white-board that I also use to list the tasks for particular things for a project. Personally I find the whiteboard more effective, not only for motivating myself but also in organizing. It's complicated, but putting the effort into planning using a physical medium is more effective to me than an electronic one. Tangibility is important, I suppose.

Comment: I'm new to scrum, but in most of my reading, scrum advocates highly recommend a physical board over software tools, even today.

Comment: But Agile ( of which Scrum  is a subset) also advocates tailoring the process to your unique circumstances while maintaining the principles.

Comment: There is another alternative today - smart boards / interactive white boards, (if one can afford it, pricings go from ~1000 up to 3000$ today, depending on size and features). Don't know however how well this works for a scrum team.

Answer (score 5):

I am currently working in a Scrum team that consists of a mixture of on-site and off-site developers. The lessons I have learnt so far here are:

1. You really need to use a digital board. We started out using a physical board, using a webcam to show the board to the off-site team members. The biggest problem here is that you can't get a good overview of the board. Either you see a large portion of the board but can't read the cards, or you can read the cards but not see where they are on the board.
   Also, the off-site developers can't easily refer to the board to see what the next task is that they can pick up.

   With a digital board, none of those problems exist. During the daily standup, we use a conference call with a shared desktop showing the board to ensure that we are all looking at the same part of the board. This is mostly because our board doesn't fit on one screen (it has a scrollbar).
2. Make sure that every once in a while, all team members are co-located. We found out that over time the product vision and what was meant by the different stories started to drift apart between the on-site and off-site team members. This seems to result mostly from the communication barrier that arises when you only have phone/e-mail/IM to communicate.
   We resolved this by arranging that every few weeks the entire team comes together at one location to re-align themselves. We also try to schedule the more intensive design discussions for those times.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no great answer to this question.

### Physical Board

A physical board has advantages.  It's effortless to radiate, a great place to have conversations around, and promotes a pull-based workflow.  It's completely customizable and you can use whatever rules and flows you want without any impediments.  Edits to current work are easy, no harder than updating a whiteboard.  As an "experienced" board user, my favorite part is that everything is inherently disposable and "hanging on" to backlog is space-prohibitive.  I also like that our inherent laziness makes it so that we'll devolve to using cards as tokens for conversation rather than cramming every last detail onto a 3x5 card.

### Virtual Board

A virtual board is easy to share.  Most come with some constraints that arguably make it easier to get started using boards.  Unfortunately, most of them force their style of board-flow on you.  Online systems promote linking things together, ownership, and the ability to archive and hang on to anything.  You can attach all kinds of useful things to the card.  The primary disadvantage for me is that it's easy to "lose" and forget in a browser tab.  I'm also frustrated by the difficulty in finding the "right way" to edit a card because my default method of throwing the old one away is usually punished in strange ways.

---

In the end, the key question for me is:  **Do I want to treat my remote teammates as second-class citizens?**  Because that's the reality if there's a "board of record" and it lives on-site.

You can do things to make a virtual board better.  Dedicating monitors or workstations to the board helps with radiating it and promoting conversation.  Making a physical board better for remote workers is tougher.  I've seen people do the remote update of two physical boards, and that process does promote some shared understanding, but it is a significant time investment.

Answer (score 1):

This should not work alright.

The dual-maintenance that you mention is not only an annoyance, but a problem that may lead to work duplication while also needing extra work just for syncing the board.

I'm not sure if you remember the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) from any Databases course, it basically says that your model will fail to be correct, or fast enough if you want it to be distributed (2 boards are enough).

It may not be correct because the possible work duplication, or it may not be 'fast enough' if you have to lock the other board to do some changes on both (maybe fast is not the correct term here, but I promise that keeping the boards on sync will be completely annoying and I would feel sorry for the guy that have to do that).

Answer (score 1):

We use a physical whiteboard and also Jira as our virtual Scrum board because we have team members that work remotely, as well as one member who resides in India (the rest are in the US). We consider the virtual Scrum board in Jira to be the "board of record" and our BSA updates the physical board to match it each morning, takes a picture of it and sends it via email to the team. Some team members find value in receiving this daily photo, but I (Scrum Master) think it is a waste of time/energy, since the virtual board is available and more up-to-date. I keep it open on my desktop and refer to it numerous times throughout the day to monitor progress.

In my opinion, the value of the physical board is to show others that are not on the team (i.e. executives, other teams, etc.) what our team is working on and current status and progress.

Comment: I know a highly regarded Agile shop that has *very* large monitors around the office that display the current state of the Trello (or whatever online tool the given team is using) for each team. That way everything is always in sync _and_ you get the "radiation" benefit.